# Cannot insert extracted json into dataframe column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has a json array as the values of one column. I want to select one of those as the values of the column and get rid of the rest. I have gotten the desired values into a series but I can't figure out how to join them back to the DataFrame in place of the existing column:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bank_account': [101, 102, 201, 301],
    'data': [
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 1000, "minimum": -500}, "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 2, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 2000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 0}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 200, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 3000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Bob"}',        
        '{"uid": 300, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 4000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Carol"}'        
    ]},
    index = ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol']
)

lst = []
for d in df['data']:
    d = pd.read_json(d, lines=True)['uid'].values[0]
    lst.append(d)
s = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df['data'] = s
print(s)
print(df)
```

returns

```
     0
0  100
1  100
2  200
3  300
       bank_account  data
Alice           101   NaN
Alice           102   NaN
Bob             201   NaN
Carol           301   NaN
```

currently and I don't know why the data column shows all nan values. Any help appreciated.

Updated Issue: Some of the rows have lists of json arrays instead of just one. Here is what I have so far:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bank_account': [101, 102, 201, 301],
    'data': [
        '[{"uid": 100, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 1000, "minimum": -500}, "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Alice"},{"uid": 150, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 1000, "minimum": -500}, "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "jer"}]',
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 2, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 2000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 0}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 200, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 3000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Bob"}',        
        '{"uid": 300, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 4000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Carol"}'        
    ]},
    index = ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol']
)

# df["data"] = df["data"].apply(lambda x: pd.read_json(x, lines=True)["uid"][0])

df["data"] = df["data"].apply(lambda array : (",".join(list(map(lambda x : pd.read_json(x, lines=True)["uid"][0], array),(df['data'])))))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bank_account': [101, 102, 201, 301],
    'data': [
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 1000, "minimum": -500}, "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 100, "account_type": 2, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 2000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 0}}, "user_name": "Alice"}',
        '{"uid": 200, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 3000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Bob"}',        
        '{"uid": 300, "account_type": 1, "account_data": {"currency": {"current": 4000, "minimum": 0},  "fees": {"monthly": 13.5}}, "user_name": "Carol"}'        
    ]},
    index = ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol']
)

df["data"] = df["data"].apply(lambda x: pd.read_json(x, lines=True)["uid"][0])
```

Your code does not work because `df` and `s` have different indices. If you want to fix your code set `df['data'] = s[0].values` (instead of `df['data'] = s`) before your two print statements.

Comment: Thanks! Using apply looks much cleaner than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

As @rachwa notes, the issue is that the indexes don't match because the index of `s` is numbers while the index of `df` is names. If you assign `lst` directly instead of casting it to a DataFrame, you will get the desired outcome, i.e.

```
df['data'] = lst
```

would work as expected.

You could also use `json.loads` instead of `read_json` (it should be faster):

```
import json
df['data'] = [json.loads(d)['uid'] for d in df['data']]
```

Output:

```
       bank_account  data
Alice           101   100
Alice           102   100
Bob             201   200
Carol           301   300
```

Comment: Hi @enke, thanks for the suggestion! I ran this on the bigger dataset (the one I posted was a test set) and realized that some of the values are lists of json arrays. Any Idea how to tackle that. I have updated the original post with a sample row to create the issue as well as my best stab at it so far.

Comment: @JustinBenfit maybe use a nested list comprehension like: `[[json.loads(d)['uid'] for d in li] for li in df['data']]`

Comment: I tried this (maybe I have it wrong) df["data"] = [[json.loads(d)['uid'] for d in li] for li in df['data']] and got JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)